# Android SQLiteException does not show proper cause of the exception

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, google-play-console

I have a keyboard app, and adding word and getting word suggestions when the user types something, so I call this method whenever the user types something.

I have a method to get data from sqlite db:

```
public ArrayList<String> getWordStartingWith(String word) {
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT word FROM suggestion WHERE word LIKE '" + word + "%' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10";
    Cursor cursor = getDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        results.add(cursor.getString(0));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return results;
}
```

getDatabase:

```
private SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
    if (mDatabase == null) {
        mDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return mDatabase;
}
```

The crash that I see in the Google Play Console in Android Vitals:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (SQLiteConnection.java)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:903)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare (SQLiteConnection.java:514)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init> (SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init> (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query (SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery (SQLiteDatabase.java:1347)
    at com.myapp.MyDatabase.getWordStartingWith (MyDatabase.java:1)
```

I am not able to reproduce it and I am also not sure what is causing this issue. Can some one please help me out in understanding what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems like sql statement preparation faces an issue - like malformed statement as a result of sql injection. This is data driven, you should probably try to get some bad data into that "word" param

Comment: @ror Thank you let me check that out